# problems about tf.data.Dataset.from_generator function in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I hope to use tf.data.Dataset.from_generator to help me generate the input data flow. However, when I read two images and crop them to [255,255,3] shape, I failed to generate the input data flow. 
Error message is

> InvalidArgumentError: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Code is as follows:

### function sample_generator to generate some data

```
instance_image_2 = tf.reshape(instance_image_2, [255,255,3])
exemplar_image_2 = tf.reshape(exemplar_image_2, [255,255,3])
yield exemplar_image_2,instance_image_2
```

### another function

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(sample_generator,output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32),output_shapes=(tf.TensorShape([255,255,3]), tf.TensorShape([255,255,3])))
```

when compiled, I get the error message.

I am sure that the shape of every tensor is right.

Comment: `from_generator`seems to be using `PyFunc` internally. Shouldn't it be returning numpy arrays of images ?

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan Thanks for you kindness. Yes, the from_generator uses PyFunc internally. So, you mean that function sample_generator should output numpy arays instead of tensors?